# periodic orbits in Gutzwiller's trace formula

Tags: mathematical-physics, semiclassical

It is said that in the Gutzwiller trace formula, one sums over the periodic orbits.

I do not know how to derive the formula, but a simple question arises for me.

That is, for some classical systems, there could be no periodic orbits at all. For example, take a 2d **anisotropic** harmonic oscillator, and let the ratio between the x- and y-direction frequencies be **irrational**. Then, the orbit can never be closed!

But the density of state for the quantum version of the model is well defined.

So, what does the periodic orbit really mean?